# how to make the open file innside the script work?

Tags: python, tkinter

*when I push save button its save to files like it should, but when I try to open the file it dosent work, I get an error.The Error message say:
TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not _io.TextIOWrapper

i want it to open in a window and show the text there, so what have I done wrong?*

I think it something inside the "gape" function that isn't properly done

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.title("Write to File")

def write():
    data = "\n" + "navn: " + txt_name.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Etternavn: " + txt_konto.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Telefon nr: " + txt_kid.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Epost: " + txt_beløp.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    file = open("data.txt", "a")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    txt_name.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_konto.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_kid.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_beløp.delete("1.0", END)
    

def read():
 create_file = open("data.txt", "a+")
 create_file.close()
 file_read = open("data.txt", "r")
 return file_read

def gape():
    root = read()
        
    text_widget = Tk(root)
    text_widget.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    scrollbar.config(command=text_widget.yview)
    text_widget.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
        text_widget.insert(INSERT, f.read())



lbl_name = Label(window, text="Navn:").pack()
txt_name = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
txt_name.pack()

lbl_konto = Label(window, text="Etternavn").pack()
txt_konto = Text(window, height = 1, width=20)
txt_konto.pack()

lbl_kid = Label(window, text="telefon nr").pack()
txt_kid = Text(window, height=1,width=20)
txt_kid.pack()

lbl_beløp = Label(window,text="Epost").pack()
txt_beløp = Text(window,height=1,width=20)
txt_beløp.pack()

btn_write = Button(window,text="Lagre", command=write).pack()
btn_read = Button(window,text="Åpne", command=gape).pack()

btn_close = Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy)
btn_close.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: _" ... it dosent work, I get an error."_ - what is the error? Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: Why do you pass the file handle open in `read()` to `Tk()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.

Create a new top level window in your `gape` function, and fill it with the contents of the file you read in in the read widget, and then fill the text widget in the newly created top level window, and call mainloop on the new window.

```
import os
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.title("Write to File")

def write():
    data = "\n" + "navn: " + txt_name.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Etternavn: " + txt_konto.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Telefon nr: " + txt_kid.get(1.0, "end-1c") + "\n" + "Epost: " + txt_beløp.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    file = open("data.txt", "a")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    txt_name.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_konto.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_kid.delete("1.0", END)
    txt_beløp.delete("1.0", END)


def read():
    file_read = ""
    if os.path.exists("data.txt"):
        file_read = open("data.txt", "rt", encoding="utf8").read()
    return file_read

def gape():
    text = read()
    frame = Tk()
    text_widget = Text(frame)
    text_widget.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    scrollbar.config(command=text_widget.yview)
    text_widget.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    text_widget.insert(INSERT, text)
    frame.mainloop()



Label(window, text="Navn:").pack()
txt_name = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
txt_name.pack()

Label(window, text="Etternavn").pack()
txt_konto = Text(window, height = 1, width=20)
txt_konto.pack()

Label(window, text="telefon nr").pack()
txt_kid = Text(window, height=1,width=20)
txt_kid.pack()

Label(window,text="Epost").pack()
txt_beløp = Text(window,height=1,width=20)
txt_beløp.pack()

Button(window,text="Lagre", command=write).pack()
Button(window,text="Åpne", command=gape).pack()

btn_close = Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy)
btn_close.pack()

window.mainloop()
```